# VBA current date reads mixes date systems

Tags: excel, vba, date, userform

I have an excel with userform where one of important variables is date.
With first open and majority of user entries it should be filled with current today's date.

For this I use simple variables set in UserForm_Activate: `MyDate=Date`
Declared `Public MyDate As Date`
Later I display it in textbox, but this works fine.
I need this variable to further calculations where I allow user to increase or decrease date by 1 day or check if date is correct when edited manually in textbox.
It works very well on all computers with windows 10 we tested in our office.

The problem is that in target computer the Data variable is read in US format.
That means that today's date 1st Febuary (01.02.2023) is read as 2nd January (02.01.2023).
What is strange, partially reading Date give correct information:
Year(Date) reads 2023
Month(Date) reads 2
Day(Date) reads 1
All are correct for today.

I checked system settings and all are set to my country and my region with European system of date.
I asked IT for help, but I wish to know if there is any way to overcome this problem using vba code, is there any way to use partial correct date part readings to one variable?

None of these works correctly:

```
MyDate = Date
MyDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date))
```

This part of button function to increase date somehow can eventually give correct today's date, even trough it will give wrong reading in between.

```
MyDate = DateAdd("d", 1, MyDate )
```

For date 01.02.2023 read as 02.01.2023 it cycles 02.01.2023 --> 01.02.2023 with first use.
Then when using `MyDate = DateAdd("d", -1, MyDate )` first and go up again I can receive:

```
02.01.2023 (wrong date and start go down)
31.01.2023
30.01.2023
29.01.2023
30.01.2023 (start to go up)
31.01.2023
02.01.2023 (wrong date)
01.02.2023 (finally ends on today date)
```

More details about my code.
Fragments where I use date variables. Modified while I was fighting with the problem, and still works on all computers except the target one, with win7.
In fact MyDate is named just "Data" in my language. I used other name to avoid confusion, but here I paste original code. Only cut out some not related variable sets from userform activate.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
 
    Data = Date
    DataStr = CStr(Format(Data, "dd.mm.yyyy"))
    TextBoxData.Value = DataStr
    JestData = True
    Tydzien = WorksheetFunction.IsoWeekNum(Data)
    LabelTydzien.Caption = Tydzien
    
    Call SetSheets 'declares sheet variables
    Call WypListKlient 'fills in combobox
    
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub TextBoxData_Change()

    If Len(TextBoxData.Value) = 10 Then
        DataStr = Replace(TextBoxData.Value, ".", "-")
        If IsDate(DataStr) Then
            Data = CDate(DataStr)
            LabelKom.Caption = ""
            LabelKom.BackColor = vbButtonFace
            
            If Data > Date Then
                Data = Date
                DataStr = CStr(Format(Data, "dd.mm.yyyy"))
                TextBoxData.Value = DataStr
                CommandButtonDataT.Enabled = False
            ElseIf Data < #1/1/2000# Then
                Data = #1/1/2000#
                DataStr = CStr(Format(Data, "dd.mm.yyyy"))
                TextBoxData.Value = DataStr
                CommandButtonDataT.Enabled = True
            ElseIf Data = Date Then
                CommandButtonDataT.Enabled = False
                DataStr = CStr(Format(Data, "dd.mm.yyyy"))
                TextBoxData.Value = DataStr
            Else
                CommandButtonDataT.Enabled = True
                DataStr = CStr(Format(Data, "dd.mm.yyyy"))
                TextBoxData.Value = DataStr
            End If
            JestData = True
            Tydzien = WorksheetFunction.IsoWeekNum(Data)
            LabelTydzien.Caption = Tydzien
        Else
            LabelKom.Caption = "Zła data"
            LabelKom.BackColor = vbRed
            JestData = False
        End If
    Else
        LabelKom.Caption = "Zła data"
        LabelKom.BackColor = vbRed
        JestData = False
    End If
    
    Call SprJest
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub CommandButtonDataP_Click()
    Data = DateAdd("d", -1, Data)
    DataStr = CStr(Format(Data, "dd.mm.yyyy"))
    TextBoxData.Value = DataStr
    JestData = True
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButtonDataT_Click()
    If Data < Date Then
        Data = DateAdd("d", 1, Data)
        DataStr = CStr(Format(Data, "dd.mm.yyyy"))
        TextBoxData.Value = DataStr
        JestData = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButtonDataTeraz_Click()
    Data = Date
    TextBoxData.Value = Format(Data, "dd.mm.yyyy")
    JestData = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If `MyDate` is declared as `Date` type, then `MyDate = Date` **cannot** be wrong. The error will be happening in how you are actually using the variable (which  you have not shown).

Comment: I use it straight forward, it already converts to wrong system in `TextBoxMyDate.Value = Format(MyDate, "dd.mm.yyyy")`, and `MyWeek = WorksheetFunction.IsoWeekNum(MyDate)` --> `LabelMyWeek.Caption = MyWeek` - where it calculates it was in US system.

Comment: If the `Year`, `Month` and `Day` functions are all returning the correct numbers, then the date is correct. That means that it is your means of *formatting* the output that is the problem. What are your regional settings?

Comment: Target PC has win7 pro SP1. Date format Poland, short yyyy-MM-dd, long d MMMM yyyy. location is Poland, first day of week is Monday, all as it should. I have no admin rights on target PC thus cannot check any additional settings. Other production computer with win10 also had this problem, but I fixed it by removing additional recommended region English, leaving only Poland. I cannot find similar setting in target PC.

Comment: My work PC has also win10 and Polish settings, however main language is English, region format is Polish (current) but have recommended region English US set below. And scripts works fine on my PC, calculating dates in EU format - in this case this does not make any problems in calculations. Same works on other office PCs.

Comment: What does `Msgbox format(date, "dd.mm.yyyy")` report on the target PC?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make a workaround of this problem. It is not a good solution but works on target PC so far.
I just changed system date format to match used on my office and others PCs, which is dd.MM.yyyy.